# Why we have to use url for acessing php file and not local file access?

Tags: php

Why do we have to use url while accessing a php file from some other file but cannot do the same by mentioning file path. If I mention the file path then it is showing code.

Comment: it seems you are seriously lacking the **fundamentals** - i suggest reading up a *lot* before writing any code yourself.
to answer shortly: because you need a program that *executes* the php-file - in this case, the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a scripting language. It is used to make dynamic web pages. 
By using a URL (with an IP, such as 127.0.0.1, localhost or any other IP), you are actually pinging a web server like Apache. By using a file path, you are not running any PHP parser (interpreter/compiler), thats why it simply shows you the code.

When you are entering a URL (e.g. `http://localhost:8000`), Apache receives your request, forwards it to PHP interpreter which is responsible to parse the requested PHP file, it then generates pure HTML and sends it back to the web server. At the end, web server is only responsible to send back the generated HTML to browser for rendering, that's why you are seeing a real web page and not plain PHP code.

**Note:** PHP code can also run without using any web server. It is also used by command line, it only need PHP Parser. For more information read this- https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php